# Django: how to pass template list to JavaScript onclick method?

Tags: javascript, django, onclick, django-templates

I would like to pass the template list to JavaScript on the `onclick` function.

I know that I can pass specific parameter.

```
onclick="selectRows({{ rows.0 }})"

function selectRows(row) {
    console.log(row);
}
// log: 1
```

but if I send list I get an error

```
onclick="selectRows({{ rows }})"

function selectRows(row) {
    console.log(row);
}
// Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <
```

Is there a way to send to JavaScript the whole list?

Comment: instead of sending value through method you can keep a hidden field and get that value on your function
<input type="hidden" value="({{rows.0}})"/>
var myVar = document.getElementById("myVar").value;

Comment: But, I can send the rows.0 to the JavaScript. The problem is if I try to do it with only rows (list of rows)...